# Array iteration in Dust.js

Tags: dust.js

I have array `unitAttributes` thats is passed to Dust and it can contain 0 or more elements. Now I need to echo all elements inside but no more then 6. I've been trying all kinds of solutions and the best one I came up is

```
{#unitAttributes}
  {@lt key=$idx value=6}
     {unitAttributes[$idx]}
  {/lt}
{/unitAttributes}
```

This way it iterates six times, but only echoes first element of the array. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your code works fine currently for me.

Comment: With this code I get first element echoed six time instead of first six elements being echoed once each. Lets say i have array with values (1,2,3,4,5,6) this code will echo 1,1,1,1,1,1 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: With what version of dust? It works properly for me as written.

Comment: Hmm maybe. We fixed problem with php so it works as intended now. Thank you for your time.